# Kubuntu 14.04 crashes on boot on Asus PC

Tags: boot, kubuntu, crash

After successfully installing Kubuntu 13.10 (64bit) on my Asus PC, I tried to upgrade to 14.04.  After the upgrade completed and I tried to restart, the boot process crashes with a kernel panic, see screenshot below:

[image]

The same problem occurs when I try and boot directly from a USB stick  from the .iso image.

Version 13.10 however works just fine (I have to reinstall this old version now)

Answer (score 0):

I'll be upgrading my ASUS eee to 14.04 (32bit) next week. I had problems with past kernal images. On a working version or from the command line I use;

Linux Image clean

```
lsb_release -a; uname -a; dpkg -l | grep linux-image
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

The 1st line gives you all the images stored on your system. Remove all except for the most current. This has been resolving the problem for me. But once again - I'm using the 32bit not the 64bit version.

If it's remains an issue - file a bug report; and ask to extend the support life of 13.10 until the issues with 14.04 are resolved.

Comment: I get the same crash, however - when restarting or shutting down. I'm going to try and trace the problem. I'm also going to look for a bug report.

Comment: Found a possible solution on youtube ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd9WIcPKc-o

Comment: It looks like the kernal panic crash is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I think I'll raise a bug report and hopefully wait until 14.05.  As the youtube video indicates, it could be an issue with the graphics card

Comment: No problem. It appears to be a random one. Two upgrades no kernal panic issues; Asus eee kernal panic issue until the removal of old linux-image (recoverable from the terminal); New install (Dell) shutdown kernal panic (I'm going to try the suggestion in youtube video Wednesday).